# Http get not retrieving content in android but providing content on browser

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-get

I am submitting form data using HTTP GET method the feedback data after getting submitted successfully returns with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result><![CDATA[Submit successfully]]></result>
```

Following is the url :

"feedbackurl":

https://www.abcd.com/abcd_api/feedbacksubmit/create?nid=9123&showid=general&cid=1&fullname=saga&contactno=876431598&usermsg=Testing+time+&email=nxkdh%40jcih.com&1402911256293

The above url provides the content in xml format provided at start of question.

The code i use to connect to http is:

```
String formSubmitURL = homeURL+"feedbacksubmit/create?nid=9123&showid="+feedbackShowId+"&cid="+URLEncoder.encode(cId, "UTF-8")+"&fullname="+URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8")+"&contactno="+URLEncoder.encode(phNO, "UTF-8")+"&usermsg="+URLEncoder.encode(userMsg, "UTF-8")+"&email="+URLEncoder.encode(userEmail, "UTF-8")+"&"+System.currentTimeMillis();
            connection = new HttpConnection(DataHanlder);               
            connection.create(HttpConnection.GET,formSubmitURL , null);
```

The form submitting is done in async task. The problem is if i hardcode the url of "feedbackurl" I get the reply (xml format) in data handler.

But if i pass it the way i am passing in "formSubmitURL" nothing is retrieved in dataHandler. But the same url hit on browser gives me the xml output in reply.

Can anyone help me find root cause of the problem or solution to this.
I know the question posted here is confusing but I am not able to explain it in better way than this.

Following is my data handler code:

```
private Handler DataHanlder = new Handler()
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        switch (msg.what)
        {
        case HttpConnection.DID_START:
            break;
        case HttpConnection.DID_SUCCEED:
            if(msg.obj!=null)
            {
                Log.i("FEEDBACK DATA FROM SERVER",""+msg.obj.toString());
                resultFromServer = msg.obj.toString();
                if(resultFromServer.contains("successfully"))
                {
                    if (pd.isShowing())
                    {
                        pd.dismiss();
                    }
                    showAlertDialog(getActivity(), "Thank You!", "We appreciate your valuable feedback.", false);
                    //Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.baseActivityContext, "Thank You!\n We appreciate your valuable feedback.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (pd.isShowing())
                    {
                        pd.dismiss();
                    }
                    showAlertDialog(getActivity(), "FeedBack Data Submit", "Your Feedback data is not submitted.", false);
                    //Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.baseActivityContext, "Your Feedback data is not submitted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
            break;
        case HttpConnection.DID_ERROR:
            if(pd!=null)
            {
                if (pd.isShowing())
                {
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};
```

Comment: If you are submitting form data it is better to use HTTP POST instead of HTTP GET. What is the value of `homeURL`? Do you use any sessions? If yes, how do you handle/transfer the session variable? Also note that in xml `&` is encoded to `&amp;`, it can cause some problems in the URL. What do you mean by 'nothing is retrieved'? Do you receive and error code? Do output is different from what you desired?

Comment: At other place in project where I am using same piece of code for retrieving xml from server I am getting contents of xml. The same piece of code is not working. When I open same url in browser The URL i logged after encoding, I am getting xml there on browser but the code is not retrieving the data. By doing post i am not getting expected reply from server.